# How to convert list file to matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list file as below:

```
> results
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "1"            "inflammation" "37.5"         "A"            "B"           
[6] "F"           

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "1"         "Apoptosis" "37.5"      "C"         "G"         "H"        

[[1]][[1]][[3]]
[[1]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "1"      "Repair" "25"     "A"      "H"     

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "2"            "inflammation" "20"           "F"           

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[[2]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "2"         "Apoptosis" "40"        "G"         "H"        

[[2]][[1]][[3]]
[[2]][[1]][[3]][[1]]
[1] "2"      "Repair" "20"     "H"
```

Also this is the output of dput function:

```
dput(results)
list(list(list(list(c("1", "inflammation", "37.5", "A", "B", 
"F")), list(c("1", "Apoptosis", "37.5", "C", "G", "H")), list(
    c("1", "Repair", "25", "A", "H")))), list(list(list(c("2", 
"inflammation", "20", "F")), list(c("2", "Apoptosis", "40", "G", 
"H")), list(c("2", "Repair", "20", "H")))), list(list(list(c("3", 
"inflammation", "25", "F")), list(c("3", "Apoptosis", "25", "C"
)), list(c("3", "Repair", "0")))), list(list(list(c("4", "inflammation", 
"50", "A", "B", "F")), list(c("4", "Apoptosis", "33.3333333333333", 
"G", "H")), list(c("4", "Repair", "33.3333333333333", "A", "H"
)))))
```

**Then I want to make a matrix like this**

```
    Number         pathway              wight     genes
    1                inflammation       37.5      A, B, F           
    1                Apoptosis          37.5      C, G, H
    1                Repair             25         A, H
    2                inflammation       20          F           
    2                Apoptosis          40         G, H
    2                Repair             20          H
```

**Is there any trick for this? genes columns includes various number of genes.**

Comment: Please paste the output of `dput(results)` into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably approach the issue at hand like *shadow* did above, but here's also an alternative recursive implementation that does not fix the number of unlists, i.e. it can handle varying depth within the list of lists. 
It just traverses the tree until it finds an element other than *list* and performs some specified formatting on it, and finally *rbinds* it all to a single matrix:

```
recurse.format <- function(
    x, 
    format = function(z) { c(z[1:3], ifelse(length(z)>3, paste(z[4:length(z)], collapse=","), NA)) } 
){
    if(class(x) == "list"){
        do.call("rbind", lapply(x, FUN=recurse.format))
    }else{
        format(x)
    }
}

mat <- recurse.format(results)
colnames(mat) <- c("Number", "Pathway", "Weight", "Genes")
print(mat)


> print(mat)
      Number Pathway        Weight             Genes  
 [1,] "1"    "inflammation" "37.5"             "A,B,F"
 [2,] "1"    "Apoptosis"    "37.5"             "C,G,H"
 [3,] "1"    "Repair"       "25"               "A,H"  
 [4,] "2"    "inflammation" "20"               "F"    
 [5,] "2"    "Apoptosis"    "40"               "G,H"  
 [6,] "2"    "Repair"       "20"               "H"    
 [7,] "3"    "inflammation" "25"               "F"    
 [8,] "3"    "Apoptosis"    "25"               "C"    
 [9,] "3"    "Repair"       "0"                NA     
[10,] "4"    "inflammation" "50"               "A,B,F"
[11,] "4"    "Apoptosis"    "33.3333333333333" "G,H"  
[12,] "4"    "Repair"       "33.3333333333333" "A,H"
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should `unlist` the results a few times. Then you have to `paste` the genes together and finally you can `rbind` the data. Here's how this could look like.

```
lst <- unlist(unlist(unlist(results, recursive=FALSE), recursive=FALSE), recursive=FALSE)
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, 
       function(x){
         data.frame(Number=as.numeric(x[1]), 
                    pathway=x[2], 
                    weight=as.numeric(x[3]), 
                    genes=paste(x[4:max(4, length(x))], collapse=", "))
       }))
df

##    Number      pathway   weight   genes
## 1       1 inflammation 37.50000 A, B, F
## 2       1    Apoptosis 37.50000 C, G, H
## 3       1       Repair 25.00000    A, H
## 4       2 inflammation 20.00000       F
## 5       2    Apoptosis 40.00000    G, H
## 6       2       Repair 20.00000       H
## 7       3 inflammation 25.00000       F
## 8       3    Apoptosis 25.00000       C
## 9       3       Repair  0.00000      NA
## 10      4 inflammation 50.00000 A, B, F
## 11      4    Apoptosis 33.33333    G, H
## 12      4       Repair 33.33333    A, H
```

Comment: Yep,  and find whoever created that list(list(list(list... )))))) mess and whack 'em a few times!